Not able to set up amazon payfort for react native for android. It is not able to find the desired repository so the build is getting failed
here is the erroe that I am getting in android while building the gradle and the project it is not able to find the desired repository I have tried jcentral() as well as mavenCentral() but still the build is getting failed here are the logs...
I am using this version for react-native "rn-amazon-payment-services": "^0.2.3",
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.amazon:fortpayment:+ as no versions of com.amazon:fortpayment are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/amazon/fortpayment/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amazon/fortpayment/maven-metadata.xml
       - file:/Users/mac/Documents/GenxReactNative/myhotels/myhotelssa/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/amazon/fortpayment/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/amazon/fortpayment/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/amazon/fortpayment/maven-metadata.xml
     Required by:
         project :app > project :rn-amazon-payment-services

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html



I have given the folowing permissions
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
as well as added this to my build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0')
        classpath('com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9')
        classpath('com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:4.0.1')
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://android-sdk.payfort.com' }
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0')
        classpath('com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9')
        classpath('com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:4.0.1')
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://android-sdk.payfort.com' }
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"


Thanks in advance for any solutions to this problem.

Fixed the issue just add repositories in all projects object at the end of your gradle and leave the earlier one as it is
